# How can I make a new list where each list is based on an items index in the main list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

For example:

```
Mainlist = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]

output = [1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]
```

Mainlist should be split based on indexes of each value in the sublists. So each value at index[0] should be grouped with the other values an index[0], and so on.

Is there a simple pythonic way to do this?

Comment: `zip(*Mainlist)` will do this

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip()` to pair up elements of two lists.

```
>>> Mainlist = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
>>> output = list(zip(*Mainlist))
>>> output
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```